# It is possible to disable type checking in PHP 7?

Tags: php

It seems like the `strict_types` directive still throws a `TypeError` when it's disabled:

https://repl.it/repls/ImpeccableUncomfortableGrub

Is it possible to disable any runtime checking of types?

Why: We have a very large codebase that we are migrating to PHP 7.1. We'd like to be able to fill in many return types from the existing annotations so that development can catch bugs sooner. However if we did this it would break many things in production (since the code flow would change).

Comment: Why just leave production as it is? And the new version (that I hope you are testing) will run on PHP 7?

Comment: It's a very large codebase (400k+ lines), a complete regression test would be unfeasible. We want to be able to start picking up errors on dev for a while until we are comfortable to turn it on in production.

Comment: In short, no. And let me guess, you're migrating from < 5.4?

I think you're going to have to start writing unit tests and going piece by piece.

Comment: @Difster - If the code base is large as this person says - should unit tests already be in place

Comment: @EdHeal - Yeah, you would think but you'd be surprised. More often than not, this isn't the case.

Comment: Your get errors if you pass a string to something that requires an int anyway, regardless of strict type.. https://3v4l.org/7YDHT see 5.6 `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to inc() must be an instance of int, string given`
`

Comment: All enabling strict types does is disable [weak type conversion](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints#behaviour_of_weak_type_checks). If you've provided type-hints (scalar or otherwise) in one part of your codebase, then you'll need to honour them in the others. So as @Difster said: *in short, no.*

Answer (score 1):

Official answer, no. It's not going to happen. Unfortunately, you're either going to have to just slog through it, write unit tests or perhaps even write some custom code to help with the transitions. And with 400k+ lines, it's not going to be easy.

Comment: This is what technical debt looks like, and OP's choices are to either kick the can further down the road until it's even worse, potentially unavoidable, and something that needs to be addressed within a timeframe that renders addressing it impossible OR to bite the bullet and start chipping away at it.

Comment: Yup. Exactly. I suspect there's been a lot of can kicking going on already though and the OP is at the bullet stage.